# Creating bathymetry maps using sonar data in SAGA

Tags: mapping, bathymetry, subsurface

I am a geologist, however somewhat of a newbie to GIS.

As a personal project, I am looking to create some bathymetric maps of some local fishing lakes.

I am looking to do this using free open source programs at zero cost, and have initially downloaded SAGA. I am aware that QGIS may be an alternative if that's better suited.

I have plenty of raw sonar data in lat/long/depth format which effectively gives me xyz.

What I would like to know is a can anyone provide me with a basic outline of how to import and transform this data into a 3d bathymetric map to show a contoured / shaded lake bed surface?

Comment: I'd suggest points to raster, followed by simple hillshading, perhaps overlaid with contours.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the heads up. The sonar data is currently exported form my sonar device in excel / .csv format. Can the conversion to raster be done within a GIS program like SAGA or does that need to be done separately?

Comment: Go for QGIS. It includes SAGA and does more, including stuff like going from point to raster, as per the link in the comment that BERA made.

Comment: GMT is pretty good but slow to learn. See https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/tutorial/session-3.html and https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/tutorial/session-4.html. The surface method https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/surface.html with lake polygons used as breaklines can give nice results if the echo lines are not very far apart. QGIS + GRASS works as well. If you rather spend some money instead of lot of your time the commercial product Reefmaster is made for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

SAGA is a good choice, to start with.

To generate a surface (a digital model of your data) you must interpolate

**Procedure at SAGA:**

1. Save your data x,y,z in a data table, csv, txt, xlsx.
2. Activate SAGA, in Open locate and load the file
3. Then on menu `Geoprocessing > Shapes > Construction >Generate shapes`.
   In the dialog box shown, configure the input fields (x,y,z) and as output `create`, shape type point
   [image]
4. You can visualize your points by selecting them, right click `add to map`
   [image]
5. **INTERPOLATION:** You have many options, go to `Geoprocessing > Grid > Gridding > interpolation` or `Spline interpolation`
   [image]
6. Each method has its own configuration options. In addition, you can configure the evaluation of error metrics to assess the performance of the method.
   [image]
7. Click on Ok, the surface is generated, visualize it with add to map
   [image]

**Isolines, contoured**

Geoprocessing > Shapes-Grids Tools> Vectorization > Contour lines for Grid
[image]

**Shaded**
[image]

Comment: I have managed to get the points in to the shape file in SAGA, however when i go to grid and interpolate, i am just getting a solid blue square. Almost as though it is not picking up the 'Z' values perhaps? In QGIS i can again get the points into a layer, but am struggling to get them to change to a vector or raster.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem. XYZ data to a mesh....don't think ppl understand a mesh
my navigation software on my boat exports in XYZ lat/long/depth import into GIS does not work....Enclosed photo is Bathymetric mesh in nav software...nice mesh

Python has XYZ import features????

[image]